# neutralinojs and Blazor in Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, neutralinojs

I try some platform to create Linux Desktop application with Blazor (Including ElectronNET), but in most case its empty self advertising without really opportunity to do even simplest task.
Therefore I'm still in searching a good platform to make desktop apps in Linux with Blazor.
Is **neutralinojs** good fit to this task including development in VS CODE and deployment to end-user?

Answer (score 1):

Neutralinojs is a lot like Electron. The main difference being that Neutralinojs does not use npm or is based on chromium.

This makes Neutralinojs faster than Electron. If you desire to make desktop apps with HTML, CSS, or JS then Neutralinojs would be a good fit for you!

I have tried both and I can tell you that Neutralinojs is the best at a quick startup.

Neutralinojs will work great with any code editor. You can even use the terminal that VS Code provides.

After you finish writing the code for your project, you can run the build command. This command will make executables for any OS including Linux.